# Who is the oldest character in the MCU, in real-world terms?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, history-of

By oldest character I don't mean the age of the character in the story, but rather in our world.  Most comics heroes have been around for decades.  For example, [Spider-Man was first introduced in 1962.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man)

Out of all the characters who have appeared on-screen in any MCU movie or TV show, which one has been around the longest as a comic book character?

Comment: On the (unlikely) chance that you don’t want to insist that the first reference to the character actually be in a Marvel comics publication, Odin (and possibly some of the other Æsir seen in the MCU) wins by at least two thousand years, as there are references to him dating all the way back to pre-Roman Europe.

Comment: https://screenrant.com/marvel-oldest-superhero-silver-surfer-immortal/#:~:text=Recent%20events%2C%20however%2C%20reveal%20that%20at%20least%20ONE,past%20after%20being%20caught%20in%20a%20black%20hole.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I believe that would go to both Captain America (Steve Rogers) and Bucky Barnes who both premiered in [*Captain America Comics* Issue 1](https://www.marvel.com/comics/issue/7849/captain_america_comics_1941_1) that was released in March 1941.

[image: Captain America Comics issue 1 front cover showing Steve punching Hitler]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

Interestingly, the next debut of an MCU character in Marvel Comics that I can find I think is actually [Jimmy Woo](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/James_Woo_(Earth-616)) (*Ant-Man and the Wasp*, *WandaVision*) who debuted in [*Yellow Claw Vol. 1* Issue 1](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Yellow_Claw_Vol_1_1) (1956).

[image: Yellow Claw Issue 1 front cover]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

Comment: Upvoting because this is the most correct answer, due to the restrictions of being in the MCU, and the nature of the characters. While Vision was older, it was an entirely different Vision, and the Human Torch is not currently in the MCU except as a brief throw-away easter egg. Other possiblities of the same name but different origin include Black Widow and Falcon.

Comment: It could also arguably go to Hitler.

Comment: @Fivesideddice I think Thor has Hitler beat.

Comment: Wow, that's pretty racist even for the time.

Comment: Curiously, [this wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Marvel_Comics_superhero_debuts) indicates Captain America Comics #1 and Steve Rogers were from 1939.  I wonder why the two year discrepancy?  Also curiously, Black Widow is listed before that, at 1938.  Though it's not the Nat Romanoff one, as that one is from the early 60's.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy Yeah as mentioned above there are several characters that are earlier but aren’t the same comic counterparts to the ones in the MCU.

Comment: @Fivesideddice in that case, Franklin D. Roosevelt would probably have him beat (see, last season of Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.)

Comment: @Graham If you're talking about the Yellow Claw comic, I wouldn't be surprised if it was intended to be progressive for its time. After all, it features a Chinese-American hero, even if he's fighting a horribly stereotypical Fu Manchu/yellow peril stereotype who was recruited by Chairman Mao to overthrow the American government to replace it with communism.

Comment: Namor, the Sub-Mariner, is expected to debut in the next phase of the MCU. His first published appearance was October 1939, making him the oldest once he appears.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen There doesn't appear to be any indication he will just yet... just wild theories as usual. If he does appear I'll update this but until then...

Answer (score 22):

I could make a case for **The Human Torch** - premiered in 1939 in Marvel Comics #1

[image]

Although the character has been re-purposed from the original android (to Johnny Storm in the Fantastic Four), the original does appear in *Captain America: The First Avenger* in a Easter egg appearance at the World's Fair Expo

[image]

Comment: He was also the first Marvel character I think as well? And good spot here, it's been a while since I've watched TFA and I completely forgot about this.

Comment: Johnny Storm isn't in the MCU (yet), even discounting the switch from the android to the human Human Torch.

Comment: My only gripe with this is whether you can count a throwaway Easter Egg and homage as a character. That said I have certainly upvoted it.

Comment: This Human Torch isn't Johnny Storm, but rather an android.

Comment: I make that point in the answer.

Comment: The original *Human* Torch was an android?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- It's not *entirely* [without precedent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R.U.R.)