Which female character in the MCU had the earliest comic book debut?
I recently stumbled upon a fascinating question here: “Which character in the MCU had the earliest comic debut?” While reading through the answers, I couldn’t help but notice that they all featured male characters. 
Now, don't get me wrong, I like those characters as much as the next person, but it got me thinking…
Of all the women we've seen in MCU movies and TV shows, who had the earliest comic book debut?

Fen, mother of Namor; April 1939
The mother of Prince Namor was introduced in Motion Picture Funnies Weekly #1 (April, 1939) as Princess Fen, daughter of the Atlantean emperor Thakorr.

In the movie Wakanda Forever, Fen was portrayed by María Mercedes Coroy. That Atlantis has been renamed Talokia, and given a different backstory, doesn't change that she is essentially the same character.
Namor's cousin Namora is also quite old in comics, having debuted in    Marvel Mystery Comics #82 (May 1947)

That flew right under my radar. Thanks for pointing it out!

Surely this answer also predates the chosen answer in this question https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/244797/which-character-in-the-mcu-had-the-earliest-comic-debut? Which would make this the earliest character for that too.

@stanri: Well, along with Namor, since they debuted in the same issue - and Namor is already an answer for that question.

@stanri The chosen answer on that question is factually incorrect. The correct answer (Namor) was added, but it was a month after the check had already been handed out.

@stanri: These "first instance" questions are often difficult, in that somebody may dig up something older than what at first glance appears right. We all do the best we can - even those accepting an answer that later turns out to be incorrect.

Patsy Walker / Hellcat (November 1944)

I believe the female MCU character with the earliest comic book debut is Patricia “Patsy“ Walker (Hellcat). She made her comic book debut in Miss America Magazine #2 (November 1944).
In the MCU, Patricia “Trish” Walker, who also used the moniker “Hellcat,” first appeared in the 2015 Netflix TV series Marvel’s Jessica Jones (set in the MCU), where she is portrayed by Rachael Taylor.

Good catch! However, Namor's mother, Fen, appeared in comics six  years earlier, and appears in the MCU in Wakanda Forever.
